# change source iframe ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

How i can Refresh Iframe in ASP.NET, i need every time change source in iframe Page load work see example:

```
document.getElementById('frame1').setAttribute('src', 'Questionair.aspx');
```

every time i need go to  'Questionair.aspx' page and execute page load, in my code this source change and page load execute one time 
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reload the source of IFrame by first setting the 'src' attribute and then calling location.reload method:

```
document.getElementById('frame1').setAttribute('src', 'Questionair.aspx');
document.getElementById('frame1').contentWindow.location.reload(true);
```